# Excel Macro/VBA to scan file for a negative balance at the end of a statement

Tags: excel, vba

[Please see screenshot HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnOnG.png)I have a macro setup to automatically format 100's- 1000's of statements for my cusotomers and to rename them to an assigned 3 digit code with todays date etc etc.

They all get put into a specific folder "MM YYYY Statements".

Is their a way to scan all these files for a Negative or Positive balance at the end of the statements?

This could be done before the aforementioned macro works, so that all these customer statements are still in one file...(see below for more descrition on the macro)

When I pull the statements (multiple at once) they are all merged into one excel file on the same sheet, then a macro sorts them by customer # into seperate sheets same file, formats them, etc, etc, then splits them into seperate save files.

The ending balance of the statement is always uniquwe to how many line items the customer has, balances would be reflected on Col I-N and a master balance on Col G

Any insight would help

Comment: It's likely to be possible. Some sample data would be useful. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52953869/edit) to include it?

Comment: There are a number of ways, as @cybernetic.nomad says, some sort of sample will be required to advise.   You need to look at either how to open workbook or ADO connections to Excel as a start.

Comment: I just edited to reflect a screenshot sample